# Запись/удаление и редактирование списка в текстовом файле

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой при выполнении домашнего задания по Python.

Суть программы - создание текстового файла с данными пользователей и их паролями. А в самой программе дальнейшее редактирование и изменение данных (удаление, создание нового пользователя).

Но у меня не выходит записать и удалять строки из списка. Запутался сильно и трудно понять как решить проблему, прошу помочь и обьяснить что я делаю не так.

Вот код моей программы.

```
parol=""
passw=["90232","Soroka5","346129S"]
names=["Sasha","Nikita","Nikolai"]
    

my_file = open("data.txt", "w+")

def registration(passw,names):
    newparol=""
    while newparol !="R" :
        newparol=input("Введите новое имя: ")
        if newparol in names:
            print("Такое имя уже есть, предложите другое. \n : ")
            continue
        names.append(newparol)
        newlogin= input("Введите пароль: ")
        passw.append(newlogin)
        #control.update(newparol)
        print(passw)
        print(names)
        f = open('data.txt', 'wt')
        for s in passw:
            f.write(s + '\n')
        for s in names:
            f.write(s + '\n')
        return passw,names


def udal(passw,names):
    print("\nСписок пользователей: \n")
    print("Пароль: ", passw)
    print("Логин: ", names)
    newname=""
    while newname !="X" :
        newname=input(" Введите логин для удаления. (Или X что бы вернутся в меню.)\n : ")
    if newname in names :
        numb=names.index(newname)
        f = open('data.txt', 'w')
        
        print("Удаленно!")
        names.remove(newname)
        passw.pop(numb)
        print(passw)
        print(names)
    else:
        print("Такого имени нет. ")
    return passw,names

while parol!="X":
    parol= input(" Добро пожаловать. \n Введите X для завершения работы.\n Или введите R для создания нового пользователя. \n Введите D - что бы удалить существующего пользователя. \n Или введите свой пароль что бы войти. \n :  ")
    if parol=="R" :
       registration(passw,names)
       continue
    elif parol=="D":
        udal(passw,names)
        continue
    elif parol=="X":
        break
    elif parol in passw:
        numb=control.index(parol)    
        person=names[numb]
        print("\nПоздравляю! ", person, " - Вы в системе.")
         
    else:
        print("Ошибка в пароле. Похоже такого не существует.")
        
input("\n Досвидания!")
```

Comment: Нигде файл не загружаете. При удалении пользователя файл не сохраняете. Ну и я бы использовал словарь для хранения пар имя:пароль.

Comment: Что мне загружать если концпеция такова "Создать файл - записать в него существующие строки из словаря. Закрыть и дальше работать с этим файлом". Я просто немного туплю и не понимаю как работать с файлами.

В регистрации нового пользователя я сохранил данные которые изменил. А вот как удалять из txt.файла (импровизированая база данных в этой программе) - не знаю.

Comment: "Работать с этим файлом" подразумевает: загрузить из файла - поменять данные - сохранить в файл. Собственно, как вы предполагаете удалять из файла без этой последовательности?

Comment: @GrAnd Вы правы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def load_data():
    try:
        with open("data.txt") as f:
            users = {}
            # читаем из файла построчно
            for line in f:
                # в каждой строке записаны имя и пароль через символ табуляции
                name, passw = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
                users[name] = passw
    except FileNotFoundError:  
        # в случае отсутствия файла инициализируем словарь начальными данными
        users = {"Sasha"   : "90232",
                 "Nikita"  : "Soroka5",
                 "Nikolai" : "346129S"
                }
    return users

def save_data():
    with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
        for name in users:
            # сохраняем пользователей построчно как имя и пароль через символ табуляции
            f.write(name + "\t" + users[name] + '\n')

def registration(users):
    while True:
        name = input("Введите новое имя (или X чтобы вернуться): ")
        if name == "X":
            return
        if name not in users:
            passw = input("Введите пароль: ")
            users[name] = passw
            break
        print("Такое имя уже есть, предложите другое.\n")
    save_data()

def udal(users):
    print("\nСписок пользователей: \n")
    print(", ".join(users))
    while True :
        name = input(" Введите логин для удаления. (Или X что бы вернутся в меню.): ")
        if name == "X":
            return
        if name in users:
            del users[name]
            print("Удаленно!")
            break
        print("Такого имени нет. ")
    save_data()

# начальная загрузка
users = load_data()        

while True:
    menu = input(" Добро пожаловать. \n Введите X для завершения работы.\n Или введите R для создания нового пользователя. \n Введите D - что бы удалить существующего пользователя. \n Или введите свой пароль что бы войти. \n :  ")
    if menu == "R":
        registration(users)
    elif menu == "D":
        udal(users)
    elif menu == "X":
        break
    elif menu in users.values():
        # берём индекс пароля среди значений словаря
        numb = list(users.values()).index(menu)
        # берём соответствующее этому индексу имя среди ключей словаря
        name = list(users.keys())[numb]
        print("\nПоздравляю! ", name, " - Вы в системе.")
    else:
        print("Ошибка в пароле. Похоже такого не существует.")
        
input("\n Досвидания!")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь стало ясно по какой концепции нужно было делать.